# IManage Filesite 9.3.1 throws 'The system cannot find the file specified error' when checking documents out in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, activex, imanage

I have a newly built windows 10 machine. We have a ActiveX control that hooks into Imanage and opens a requested document. On my old machine this ActiveX control worked as expected but on the new PC I am getting a Imanage error dialog.

> One or more documents could not be checked out. The operation could not be performed on these document(s). The document XXX could not be checked out. The system cannot find the file specified.

I am using IE 11 with the same security settings. As I am getting an Imanage error, that implies that the ActiveX control is working thus Imanage is the issue?

I am using Filesite 9.3.1 on both machines. I am not an expert on Imanage and how it works so I could be missing something simple.

Comment: You may need to take a look at the underlying DMSLog.txt files on the FileSite servers. These would normally be located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Autonomy\WorkSite\Server\Logs on your header servers. There may be more detail in those.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Based on available information it sounds like the checkout path (NRTPortble directory) is not a valid path on your Win10 box. Check the registry to make sure NRTPortable is pointing to a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons that this could be happening:

1. As already mentioned by Yevgeny, the NRT locations may be invalid, the locations are stored in the registry at:

   NRTEcho:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0\Common\General\Echo

   NRPortbl:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0\Common\General\Portable

though this may be different based on your individual iManage implementation.

2. If this issue is only occurring on certain documents, one's that are created via a script for example. It may be that the files are zero kilobyte. Have seen this happen before when documents are being dynamically created from sharepoint templates.